# Parallelize with omp atomic

Tags: c, openmp

I wonder if these two loops are equivalent in performance, with `a` being a global int and M an int[]:

```
#pragma omp for
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    #pragma omp atomic
    a += M[i];
}

for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    a += M[i];
}
```

In other words, is it worth parallelizing it, knowing that the only instruction must be atomic?
I personnaly think that it's not possible to speed up the second loop because the affectation will never be executed more than once simultaneously.

Comment: Benchmark? Also read up on the `reduction()` clause.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your loop without synchronisation is that the result may not be correct.

To speed up the computation, you can use the `reduction` clause, this way:

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:a)
```

You can easily make some counter to the the effect on calculations:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main(void)
{
    long long int setup = 0, sum_atomic = 0, sum_simple = 0, sum_reduc = 0, sum_noomp = 0;
    const int N = 100000;
    int *M = malloc(sizeof *M * N);
    double tick[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        M[i] = i;
    }

    /* setup zone to prevent measuring first parallel zone drawback */
    #pragma omp parallel for 
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        setup += M[i];
    }

    /* using single thread execution */
    tick[0] = omp_get_wtime();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        sum_noomp += M[i];
    }        

    /* using reduction */
    tick[1] = omp_get_wtime();
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum_reduc)
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        sum_reduc += M[i];
    }

    /* using openmp, the wrong way */
    tick[2] = omp_get_wtime();
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        sum_simple += M[i];
    }

    /* using atomic keyword */
    tick[3] = omp_get_wtime();
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        #pragma omp atomic
        sum_atomic += M[i];
    }

    tick[4] = omp_get_wtime();

    printf("noomp:  %lld, in %.0f us\n", sum_noomp,  1000000.*(tick[1]-tick[0]));
    printf("reduc:  %lld, in %.0f us\n", sum_reduc,  1000000.*(tick[2]-tick[1]));
    printf("simple: %lld, in %.0f us\n", sum_simple, 1000000.*(tick[3]-tick[2]));   
    printf("atomic: %lld, in %.0f us\n", sum_atomic, 1000000.*(tick[4]-tick[3]));

    free(M);

    return 0;
}
```

On a two core CPU, the result is:

```
noomp:  4999950000, in 28 us  -- single thread quite fast 
reduc:  4999950000, in 17 us  -- reduction: twice fast
simple: 2024135316, in 12 us  -- incorrect sum 
atomic: 4999950000, in 3686 us -- atomic kw: slow compared to single thread version
```

So:

- the faster way is to use openmp with `reduction`
- openmp is slower that sequencial version when using `atomic`
- openmp result is wrong when used without `reduction` or `atomic`

Details:

Compiled with gcc 8.2.1 on with `-Wall -O3 -mtune=native -march=native -fopenmp` option on [tio machine](https://tio.run/#c-gcc), using two cores of a Xeon CPU E5-2650 v4.

Comment: Just for the record, the encounter to the very first `parallel` region usually incurs a much more costly setup of the OpenMP environment than any subsequent ones. Therefore, the way your benchmark is written gives a highly unfair disadvantage to the first loop (the one using `atomic`). Likewise, to be of any true interest, your comparison should also include the time for the sequential code as a reference. And finally, you should indicate the compiler and switches you used to allow others to reproduce your results.

Comment: Thank you for having taken my comments into account. Now a last word of wisdom: never benchmark a code without full optimization level from the compiler, otherwise, the results are meaningless. Typically here, replace your `-O0` with `-O3 -mtune=native -march=native`.

Comment: @Gilles Ok, I understand. I fact, first, I turned optimization off, because I fear that the compiler optimize the `for` loop away...

Comment: Since you print the result, that shouldn't be the case